# You need to reduce your APK file size to 100MB or use APK Expansion Files

Tags: java, android, android-layout, listview, android-studio

When I try to upload my application in Google Play I get the following error message: "You need to reduce your APK file size to 100MB or use APK Expansion Files."

Can someone explain me the steps that I have to do to expand the files? I really don't have any idea about what I have to do.

Comment: http://android-developers.blogspot.in/2012/03/android-apps-break-50mb-barrier.html

Answer (score 3):

From [Googles Developer Console Help Documentation](https://support.google.com/googleplay/android-developer/answer/113469?hl=en),

> APK files have a maximum file size, based on the Android version your
>   APK supports. If you can't support all devices with a single APK, you
>   can upload multiple APKs using the same app listing that target
>   different device configurations.
>
> 1. 100MB - APKs that target Android 2.3 and higher (API level 9-10 and
>      14+)
> 2. 50MB - APKs that target Android 2.2 and lower (API level 8 or lower)
>
> Tip: Users must run Play Store version 5.2 or higher to install 100MB
>   APKs.

Google Play is increasing the APK file size limit to 100MB from 50MB. Currently, the maximum size for an APK published on Google Play is 50 MB. You can use up to two (2) APK Expansion Files, each up to 2 GB in size, for each APK.

Comment: You can go through documentation. I have given the link. Hopefully it will clarify you.